# How do I prove that optimal strategy exists for both players in matrix game 2x2?

Tags: game-theory

I am new to game theory and mathematical proofs generally and I read in my textbook that if in a 2x2 matrix game with two players the first player has optimal strategy then for sure the second one has also, sadly I can't find any proofs and frankly I am new to the field and I am not so sure where to look or start.

Comment: Are you referring to zero sum games?

Comment: @Kaind its not said, it says only 2x2 matrix game

Comment: How do you define an optimal strategy for non-zero sum games?